# Class highlighting in documentation comments

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, xml-documentation, code-documentation

I am using MS Visual Studio 2015 and I am trying to do some documentation and description of methods I made. I use the `///` comment and would like to highlight exception class names in IntelliSense popup. So I would like to get result like `... does fancy things and sometimes blows with DivideByZeroException, because you are not Chuck.` with `DivideByZeroException` being with the same color as classes usually are *in the body of summary text*. Seen the picture below.

How this can be reproduced, please? I tried to look into MSDN database, but I didn´t managed to find a way (if it can be done).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Preface: I am the asker of this question, so this is the reason of "me-style" answer :-)

I had recently looked into this and it seems as it cannot be done as I was hoping. According to [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707172/3336667), and [this MSDN documntation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax(v=vs.140).aspx), the behaviour I was hoping to reproduce in the bulk of summary text is a speciality of `exception` documentation tag:

```
<exception cref="DivideByZeroException">Thou' are not Chuck</exception>
```

what *might* do the trick is `<c>` or `<code>` tags. Unfortunately, they do not seem to do anything in my VS2015 Express IntelliSense, so I cannot verify this.

Comment: `<c>text</c>` seems to be working in VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like below.

```
/// <summary>
/// ... does fancy things and sometimes blows with DivideByZeroException, because you are not Chuck.
/// </summary>
/// <exception cref="DivideByZeroException" />
```

I am using VS2015 community edition.

Comment: Yes I am aware of this, but I was curious if this "coloring" can be achieved in a bulk of text, not in special part "Exceptions:".